# JMS - use dynamically selectors on listener

Tags: java, spring, jms

I have a project that used spring,jsf,primefaces and I want to implement JMS (activeMQ) using jsmTemplate, my idea is to use one queue and with selectors obtain and send certain information, the selectors will be changing dynamically, so I want to use a listener but I don´t know how to define the selectors,

this is my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="pubSubDomain" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="springJmsProducer" class="com.SpringJmsProducer">
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
        <property name="destination" ref="queue.aclaraciones" />
    </bean>

        <bean id="springJmsConsumer" class="com.SpringJmsConsumer">
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
        <property name="destination" ref="queue.aclaraciones" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Opcion para tener un listener escuchando siempre -->
    <bean id="queue.aclaraciones" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="queue.aclaraciones" />
    </bean>

<bean id="messageListener" class="com.ExampleListener" />

    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="queue.aclaraciones"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
    </bean>
```

this is my listener:

```
public class ExampleListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                System.out.println(((TextMessage) message).getText());
            }
            catch (JMSException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message must be of type TextMessage");
        }
    }

}
```

is it possible to do something like that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you check the Spring Reference documentation and see the `@JmsListener` annotation. It is very useful

Comment: Man that sounds over complicated what you are doing, interesting though good luck.

Comment: @ManuelJordan do you have an example you can share with me?

Comment: @Snickers3192 I know !, this is taking me to much time but I think if I can found a solution it will be very useful

Comment: Start with the Spring Reference documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jms the rest is available through Google... There are many examples...

Comment: Hi @ManuelJordan I searched some examples and found that with the annotation JmsListener can't use dynamic selectors, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472329/jmslistener-dynamic-selector